# How to run a javascript function multiple time till you satisfy the if condition

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, alteryx

I have an Ajax call which I want run multiple times till it satisfies a particular if condition. The AJAX call gives you the job status-Running, Queued and Complete.
I am unable to get the Job status- Complete. After getting Running status it takes a couple of minutes to get the status Complete. So far I have tried the following JS. I also want to break the loop after the if condition has been met. I am also not sure if I should run the call for 100 times as it might take more than that. Thank you for your help.

My JS:

```
var pollForJob= gallery.getJob(jobId, function(job){
    var jobStat=job.status;
    console.log(jobStat);
    if(jobStat=="Complete"){
        alert("Complete");
    } else {
    // Attempt it again in one second
       setTimeout(pollForJob, 1000);
       console.log("still working");
       console.log(jobStat);
    }
},  function(response){
    var error = response.responseJSON && response.responseJSON.message || 
                 response.statusText;
    alert(error);
    // Attempt it again in one second
    setTimeout(pollForJob, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Look at `Promises`. Failing that use `setInterval` to check for the condition.

Comment: This is called long polling, and basically consists in hammering the server until it gives you the value you're waiting for. A smarter approach would be to use websockets, that would allow the server to notify the client when it's done.

Comment: calling it 100 times seems like a bad idea....

Answer (score 1):

Like Jeremy Thille said, this is called long polling. A simple way of doing it is to create a function which makes the call out to the server. Then, if it fails, use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) to queue up another request later.

```
function pollForJob() {
    gallery.getJob(jobId, function(job) {
        var jobStat = job.status;
        if (jobStat == "Complete") {
            alert("Complete");
        } else {
           // Attempt it again in one second
           setTimeout(pollForJob, 1000);
        }
    }, function(response) {
        var error = response.responseJSON && response.responseJSON.message || response.statusText;
        console.error(error);
        // Attempt it again in one second
        setTimeout(pollForJob, 1000);
    });
}
pollForJob();
```

Comment: Why wasting 1 second?

Comment: @Priya It doesn't have to be that long. If you think you'll get a response before then, then do it. But it doesn't make sense to hit the server every, say, 50ms if you don't expect to get a valid response in under 200ms.

Comment: Hello Mike, thanks for your answer for some reason this solution does not work. I also tried setInterval. It's just not detecting the if condition

Comment: @dpr If you aren't hitting your `if` statement then check what's happening on your server. You would have to be hitting your error section.

Comment: @dpr Don't forget to call `pollForJob` the first time. I'll update my answer to show that.

Comment: Hey Mike, setInterval worked for me thanks a bunch for your prompt response, really appreciate it